# Index Error in matlab compiled python package

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-compiler, index-error

so I've written a function in matlab which gives six inputs to a number of neuralnetworks saved in "nets", which is a cell array and returns a vector, containing one result per network:

```
function e = network_evaluation(s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)
    var = load("Network_single_output(6-2-1).mat", "nets");
    in = [s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]';
    n = var.nets;
    e = zeros(1,length(n));
    for i = 1:length(n)
        e(i) = n{i}(in);
    end
end
```

I have then used to Matlab Compiler SDK to get a Python Package which I succesfully installed and called in Python.
When I run my function though, I get an error:

```
Warning: Class 'network' is an unknown object class or does not have a valid 'loadobj' method.  Element(s) of this class in array 'nets' have been converted to structures.
> In net_ev (line 2)
Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).
Error in net_ev (line 7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File path, line 11, in <module>
    result = netting.net_ev(1,2,3,4,5,6)
  File path, line 80, in __call__
    nlhsWasSpecified, stdoutObj, stderrObj).result()
  File "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\compiler_sdk\pysdk_py\matlab_pysdk\runtime\futureresult.py", line 135, in result
    raise e
matlab_pysdk.runtime.MatlabRuntimeError: An error occurred when evaluating the result from a function. Details: 
  File path\net_ev.m, line 7, in net_ev
Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).
```

(I have replaced the acutally file path here with "path").
I have already tried to use 
length(n)-1
but it didn't work. Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are two index expressions in one line. My first attempt would be `h=n{i}; e(i) = h(in);` in two separate lines. Not because I expect it to solve the problem, but it reduces the possible causes.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your suggestions moved the error to line 8, which is now `e(i) = h(in);`
Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Interestingly once I call the function in python and use doubles as input arguments the error changes to `Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as you, first the warning that the network object is not being loaded properly and then the same "Array indices must be...". That's because the network is being imported as a struct. The problem seems to be a bug in the MATLAB package generation, it's not detecting the need to include the NeuralNetwork toolbox and thus when it tries to load the network object it fails.

To fix this I included a check in my function preamble to make sure the object loaded is of class "network" otherwise create it as explained [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/321077-neural-network-is-saved-as-struct-instead-of-network):

```matlab
if isa(trained_net, 'struct')
    trained_net = network(trained_net);
end
```

Once this is done and the package is exported, you will need to install the newly generated matlab runtime, since now it's including the required toolbox it changes, for me it went from 800MB to almost 3GB.

Try running your function again and this time it should work as expected